# INDEX & MATCH with multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have been trying to figure it out for what I was doing wrong

Here the explanation for what I am currently doing :

1. It is a game that customer need to guess for 4 condition (*outfit,brand,color,price*)
2. I have to match between 2 worksheets which is  customer's guessing and list (which is criteria)
3. it going to show only 2 result (**bingo,try again** like in yellow column)
4. the criteria is guessing for *outfit,brand,color* need to be exactly correct (as shown in list-worksheet)
5. for *price* it can be the other values but not less/more than 5

```html
=IF(ABS(INDEX(list!D:D,MATCH(A2,list!A:A,0),MATCH(B2,list!B:B,0),MATCH(C2,list!C:C,0))-D2)<=5,"bingo",IF(ABS(INDEX(list!F:F,MATCH(A2,list!A:A,0),MATCH(B2,list!B:B,0),MATCH(C2,list!E:E,0))-D2)<=5,"bingo","try again"))
```

- the above is formula that I use but it turned out error
- if doing correctly the result would be like in *yellow column*
- *Note column* and *orange highlights* does not involve it's just optional explanation for your understanding

[image: Customer's guessing]

[image: list]

list

Answer (score 1):

So the main reason you're running into issues is because your `list` worksheet is setup terribly.  Excel runs best with a flat-file type data structure.  It should be reformatted to this:

[image]

Then you can setup your guessing game and use a simple SUMIFS formula:

[image]

In cell E2 of the guessing game worksheet, the formula is:

```
=IF(ABS(D2-SUMIFS(list!D:D,list!A:A,A2,list!B:B,B2,list!C:C,C2))<5,"Bingo!","Try again")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! if let's say the worksheets are not allowed to change. is there other way.

Comment: @Helloworld I would really recommend adjusting the `list` sheet's data setup to match the flat-file structure as shown.  The way it currently is will only cause headaches, especially if more data gets added.  The recommended way will scale easily as more data is added.  While possible to use a formula to achieve the desired results using your shown data setup, it would be hugely unwieldy and prone to breaking